# Multiple table join query - IDs and data tables

Tags: hive, hiveql

**SOLVED turns out it was my where clause which was throwing off the results, I changed this out and added the where clause to the ON statement**

I need some help.

I have a table with 25 million IDs and 4 tables with IDs and data. I need to create a new table with these 25 million IDs as well as the associated table data from the 4 tables. Each data table will not contain the full 25 million IDs. So as an example;

ID Table:

| ID |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

Table 1

| ID | measure_a | measure_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | 3 |

Table 2

| ID | measure_f | measure_g |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4 |

etc..

Expected output:

| ID | measure_a | measure_b | measure_f | measure_g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| B | NULL | NULL | 1 | 3 |

The most important thing is the 25 million IDs are in the final table. I've tried multiple joins but end up with a hugely reduced number of IDs which I believe is due to the IDs which don't match on the join condition being filtered out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `left join`s:

```
select ids.id, t1.measure_a, t1.measure_b, t2.measure_f, t2.measure_g
from ids left join
     table1 t1
     on ids.id = t1.id left join
     table2 t2
     on ids.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. This doesn't work as by the end of the query (after 4 left joins in this case) I'm left with a record count in the tens of thousands, when the initial ID table is 25m. I need to keep all IDs, joining seems to discard any which don't match even with a left join. As an example, focusing on just 1 left join, reduces the record count of the new table to 8.3 million - subsequently this is the count for the data table it has been joined to.

Comment: I think this should work, can you please check. See that he is doing left join using ids.id with both tables.

Comment: I am indeed doing the same (using the ID from the ID table as the join condition for all joins).

Comment: I found out the issue, my where clause filter was throwing a spanner in the works. Swapping this out and adding the condition to the ON statement fixed it. Thanks both.